# How to redirect from https to http in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

I have a website with ssl currently i moved my website from previous hosting server to new hosting server.

But Google.com showing my website with `https://domainnameex.com` but i it has to be `http://www.domainnameex.com`

Comment: that domain name is just for example only

Comment: You can control this with Google WebMaster Tools

Comment: can you explain me clearly @ kay Nelson

Comment: https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=cr&ei=Xg-BUtDkE-Tx4QSJ6YGIDg#q=google+webmaster+tools You have to login with your google account and make use of their product called 'Google Webmaster tools'. once you have that you can control the way google should show your site. You must first confirm your site inside the tool.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/